# Issue using tags within my quiz

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Xcode and objective C sorry for the wacky code. I'm trying to get my quiz to uses tags to get a number from 1-4 for a set of 8 questions, the max score is 32,  if the user score between 0-8 take them to this storyboard and so-on but I'm having a issue with getting the tags to add up and and to check if the current number is less or equal to score when the next button is pressed.

Thanks for the help.

,H file

```
       IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    int currentNumber;
    int currentOperation;
    int score;

}

    - (IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)next:(id)sender;
```

.M file

```
- (IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender{

    currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (int)[sender tag];
    currentNumber = score;
}


- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {

       score = 36;
    if(currentNumber ==0 )score = currentNumber;
    else{

               score = score + currentNumber;

        }


    if (score <= 8){

            tool1ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"0-8"];
    [self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    }else if(score <=16){

            tool1ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“8-16”];
    [self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    }else if(score <=24){

            tool1ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“16-24”];
    [self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];


    }else if(score <=32){
    tool1ViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“24-32”];
    [self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CGFloat instead of int:

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (CGFloat)[sender tag];

 CGFloat currentNumber;
```

etc.

When comparing use:

```
if(currentNumber < 0.1 )
```

because floating values should not be checked if equal to something.

CGFloat is defined as float for 32 bit and double for 64 bit, but you don´t have to think about that if you use it consistently.

Comment: when i press a button it always show storyboard 0-8?? and thanks

Comment: @crispy2k12 initialize currentNumber to be 1 in the beginning. The default is zero. You should print out the number you get with NSLog(@"currentNumber: %f", currentNumber);

Comment: almost but when i get the total tags of 8, it should take me it storyboard 1 but takes me to storyboard 2 instead,or if it add up and should got to 2 it ill take me to 3 lol and thanks again

Comment: @crispy2k12 Check your math by logging each step with NSLog as shown above. The error is in your math and set the if conditions like <= 8.1 etc.

Comment: It Works i was setting the if statements to 6.0 when it should be 7.0 lol thanks for the help!!